# yii2 wrong time zone

Tags: timezone, yii2

I have in my database field. Type: TIMESTAMP (example 2015-12-23 15:38:32).
I get this time in GridView.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'date',
    'format' => 'datetime',
],
```

Formatter configured:

```
'formatter' => [
    'dateFormat' => 'php:d.m.Y',
    'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d.m.Y H:i:s',
    'defaultTimeZone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
],
```

I get time +1 from my database time. (2015-12-23 15:38:32 +1 hour = 2015-12-23 16:38:32).
I tried everithing. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure db timezone in config/main.php in afterOpen event, in db component:

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name',
        'username' => 'db_username',
        'password' => 'db_password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',

        'on afterOpen' => function($event) {
            $event->sender->createCommand("SET time_zone = '+00:00'")->execute();
        }              
    ],
```